# Closure, anonymous functions or binds on delayed functions

Tags: javascript, comparative-review

I'm calling an expensive function that dynamical changes as the end user types in a textbox. To reduce the amount of calls to the function I've used `setTimeout` to delay calling the function, and if the function is called again whilst waiting to run, it'll also remove the last function request via `clearTimeout`.

The function for this is:

```
// To not have different functions conflict
function makeDelay() {
    var timerID = false;
    return function (fn, timeout) {
        if (timerID !== false) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);
        }
        if (timeout == undefined) {
            timeout = 500;
        }
        timerID = setTimeout(function() {
            timerID = false;
            fn();
        }, timeout);
    }
}
var delay = makeDelay();
var $peoplePicker = $('.ms-peoplePicker');
var $results = $peoplePicker.find(".ms-PeoplePicker-results");
```

However I don't know what the most idiomatic way to use this function is. I know that I can use one of the following:

- A closure

  ```
  function get(input, html_output) {
      return function () {
          if (!input) {
              return;
          }
          $.ajax('/_api/pp_search/' + input).done(function (data) {
              html_output[0].innerHTML = data;
          })
      }
  }

  $peoplePicker.on('input', '.ms-PeoplePicker-searchField', function(event) {
      delay(get(event.currentTarget.value, $results));
  });
  ```
- `bind`

  ```
  function get(input, html_output) {
      if (!input) {
          return;
      }
      $.ajax('/_api/pp_search/' + input).done(function (data) {
          html_output[0].innerHTML = data;
      })
  }

  $peoplePicker.on('input', '.ms-PeoplePicker-searchField', function(event) {
      delay(get.bind(undefined, event.currentTarget.value, $results));
  });
  ```
- Anonymous functions

  ```
  function get(input, html_output) {
      if (!input) {
          return;
      }
      $.ajax('/_api/pp_search/' + input).done(function (data) {
          html_output[0].innerHTML = data;
      })
  }

  $peoplePicker.on('input', '.ms-PeoplePicker-searchField', function(event) {
      delay(function () {
          get(event.currentTarget.value, $results);
      });
  });
  ```

Using a closure seems like the nicest, as you don't have to explicitly make a delayed function at usage via `bind` or an anonymous function. However, anonymous functions seem to be the de facto way to call functions like these.

Which, if any, way should I use this function?

---

#### Notes

I ask because I made a JavaScript program that heavily used closures for this style of function, but was *really* hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you are looking for is already done in Lodash via [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) or [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle). And yes, a closure is probably the best way to do this. So let's take your closure example and improve it.

Instead of returning a function, why not just define the function normally. That way, there's no developer overhead. Devs shouldn't know about your limiter function just to make their APIs.

```
// We'll be fine with this
function get(input, html_output) {
  if (!input) return;    

  $.ajax('/_api/pp_search/' + input).done(function (data) {
    html_output[0].innerHTML = data;
  });

}
```

`delay` is a bit deceiving as the word "delay" can mean a lot of things. It can mean "pause", which then equates to `sleep` which does an entirely different thing. "debounce" and "throttle" are actually better names. Verbose names aren't that bad as well (except for the extra keystrokes). Something like `holdExecutionUntilAfter`.

Now for the implementation, let's accept a `delay` and the function we want to delay. Our return will be our "proxy" function that controls the real function from executing.

```
function holdExecutionUntilAfter(fn, delay){
  var timer = null;

  return function(){
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);

    setTimeout(function(){
      fn.apply(null, arguments);
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

As simple as that! What it does is get a reference of the real function into a closure. Then we return a "proxy" function which well be using to call the real function. When it gets called, it resets the timer and kicks off another. We use `apply` to pass in the arguments like you normally would in the regular call. Usage will be as simple as:

```
var get = delay(function(input, html_output){
  if (!input) return;    
  $.ajax('/_api/pp_search/' + input).done(function (data) {
    html_output[0].innerHTML = data;
  });
}, 500);

get(event.currentTarget.value, $results);

// or verbosely

function get(input, html_output){
  if (!input) return;    

  $.ajax('/_api/pp_search/' + input).done(function (data) {
    html_output[0].innerHTML = data;
  });
}
var proxiedGet = delay(get, 500);

proxiedGet(event.currentTarget.value, $results);
```

Comment: Thank you for the review, it's a lovely solution which reminds me of Python's `@` sugar.